# why can i not call a function of my vue component in my callback

Tags: vue.js

i am use datatables and jquery in vue and

```
> <script>
>     export default {
>       methods: {
>         ddd() {
>           alert(44444444);
>         },
>       },
>       mounted: function () {
>         let table = new DataTable("#tbl", {});
>         $("#tbl tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
>           this.ddd();
>         });
>       },
>     };
>     </script>
```

why ddd() is not work please help me

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  To receive help, please translate your question to English, but be sure to follow the [content guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is lexical scoping. the callback method you're provided is an anonymous function which redeclares the value of `this`. To solve it, use a fat arrow.

```
$("#tbl tbody").on("click", "tr", () => {
  this.ddd();
});
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton Done.